# Data class for API response structure?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit, data-class

I am using wikipedia API whose response structure is as

```
{
"batchcomplete": "",
"continue": {
"gpsoffset": 10,
"continue": "gpsoffset||"
  },
  "query": {
"pages": {
  "27667": {
    "pageid": 27667,
    "ns": 0,
    "title": "Space",
    "index": 1,
    "thumbnail": {
      "source": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/3D_coordinate_system.svg/200px-3D_coordinate_system.svg.png",
      "width": 200,
      "height": 200
    }
  },
  "28189": {
    "pageid": 28189,
    "ns": 0,
    "title": "Space Shuttle",
    "index": 8,
    "thumbnail": {
      "source": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d6/STS120LaunchHiRes-edit1.jpg/128px-STS120LaunchHiRes-edit1.jpg",
      "width": 128,
      "height": 200
    }
  },
  "28758": {
    "pageid": 28758,
    "ns": 0,
    "title": "Spacetime",
    "index": 5,
    "thumbnail": {
      "source": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d1/GPB_circling_earth.jpg/200px-GPB_circling_earth.jpg",
      "width": 200,
      "height": 150
    }
  }
}
  }
}
```

I am confused on how to use the pages object
I currently have as

```
data class APIResult(
@SerializedName("query")
val query: Query
)

data class Query(
@SerializedName("pages")
val pages: Pages
)

data class Pages(
@SerializedName("thumbnail")
val thumbnail: Thumbnail
)

data class Thumbnail(
@SerializedName("source")
val source: String
)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: that's a map of string to pages in the query object. `data class Query(val pages: Map<String, Page>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query has a pages map inside

```
data class Query(
    @SerializedName("pages")
    val pages: Map<String, Page>
)
```

And your `Pages` should actually be a single page

```
data class Page(
    @SerializedName("pageid")...
    @SerializedName("thumbnail")
    val thumbnail: Thumbnail
)
```

This is one element on a map:

```
"28189": {...}
```

You can't know each key previously, so it is a map of `String, Object` but you do know the object type which is a `Page`

So after that, you can `pages.values()` and get a list of pages or anything you can do with a Map.